# How to adjust the Bar plot to make the bars smaller?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help to adjust the size of column width in a bar plot. I use the following R script to get a barplot with a p-value, but the width of the bars (column) is too wide. Thanks

```
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

    df <- ToothGrowth
df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)
head(df, 6)

# Statistical test
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(len ~ supp) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

# Box plots with p-values
bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "supp", y = "len", fill = "supp", 
palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))


stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "supp")
bxp + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))

# Customize p-value labels using glue expression 
# https://github.com/tidyverse/glue
bxp + stat_pvalue_manual(
  stat.test, label = "T-test, p = {p}",
  vjust = -1, bracket.nudge.y = 1
) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.15)))
```

Comment: You just want the bar to be thinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a matter of width, you can specify it in this way:

```
bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "supp", y = "len", fill = "supp", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),width = 0.5)


stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "supp")

bxp + stat_pvalue_manual(
  stat.test, label = "T-test, p = {p}",
  vjust = -1, bracket.nudge.y = 1
) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.15)))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(2, 2))
```

then, using the rest it looks like this:

[image]

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: thanks, yes it is almost done. But the the chart size (x-axis) is wider, could you please also help me to fix the overall chart size (x-axis). Thanks

Comment: is this way ok?